# Variable Resistance

Tags: resistance, 555, pulse, astable, square

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCJoeF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a pulse generator, outputting square pulses with about 8% duty cycle. Tuning R2 down to 120k will result in the same high time, but a cycle of about a 20%, and 6k almost 100%. How can I control the resistance of the resistor by other means than with a rheostat, but rather with input voltage.

If there are other ways to get a pulse of ca 60 mils, from a 8% duty cycle to 100%, those are also acceptable answers. (however I'm not a fan of micro computers or something like that)

Comment: There is surely an IC out there that does what you need...

Comment: A micro would be the modern answer - use analogue input for your voltage control.

Answer (score 2):

EGG/Perkin-Elmer used to make devices called VACTROLs comprising an LED and an LDR coupled optically such that when the LED current varied, the resistance of the LDR varied in step.

They're still around in various incarnations, and a Google search for VACTROL will get you some good hits.

You can use one in your pulse generator like this:

[image]

Comment: You'd get a more linear and predictable result by putting R2 on the emitter of Q1 and getting rid of R1.  In other words, make Q1 a controlled current sink.

Comment: Nice point; I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Your real question is apparently how to generate repetitive digital pulses with variable duty cycle and frequency.  That's called PWM (pusle-width modulation).

The easiest way to produce a controllable PWM output is with a microcontroller.  This is very commonly done.  In fact, most micros have PWM generators built in for just this reason.  Once you set them up for a particular period and duty cycle, the hardware produces the pulses without further firmware interaction.  Usually there is a register you can write new duty cycle (fraction of pulse period where the pulse is high) values to on the fly.  The pulse period is usually derived by dividing down the instruction clock, and in some cases a high speed clock created just for that purpose.

In short, most micros deliberately include hardware to do exactly what you want.  Return the 666 timer with its high current draw and lots of analog components to whatever museum you got it from.  Learning microcontrollers takes some investment up front, but once you've done that it will open your world to a wide range of new possibilities.  If you're into electronics at all, this is a must nowadays, no different that knowing how to use transistors, resistors, capacitors, and opamps.

Comment: sorry, no micros

Answer (score 0):

You can use a circuit like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ559U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this case, the SR flip-flop formed by NAND1 and NAND2 (buffered by NAND3) cause the op amp to ramp up or down. This assumes RSET2 is greater than RSET1. While the input is less than VREF and the output is low, D1 prevents current from flowing in RSET2, so it can be disregarded, and the current into OA1 is $$i = \frac{V_{Control} -V_{REF}}{RSET1} $$ and the op amp will be ramping up at a rate $$ \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t} =-\frac {i}{C} $$ and the time required to ramp the op amp output from 1.5 to 7.5 volts is$$\Delta t = -\frac{C\Delta V}{i} $$ When the op amp reaches 7.5 volts, the output will be forced high, and so is the output of NAND3. Now an opposing current in RSET2 will cause the op amp to ramp down at a rate $$ \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t} =\frac {i}{C} $$ where $$i = \frac{9V - V_{Ref} - 0.7}{RSET2} - \frac{V_{Ref} -V_{Control}}{RSET1} $$ Since RSET2 is less than RSET1, the added current through RSET2 will be greater than that through RSET1, and the op amp will ramp negatively. This will continue until the output reaches 1.5 volts, when the SR flip-flop will toggle, and the cycle will start again.

The output-LOW phase is controlled by the control voltage, but is not entirely convenient, since if the 9 volts is not stable, neither will VREF, and neither will the ramp rate. This is potentially a problem for long LOW phase durations. Fortunately, this is fairly easily fixed:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJssWQ.png)</sup>

This is a difference amplifier, and will produce a "New Control" voltage of $$V = V_{Ref} -V_{Control} $$

The only restriction on parts is the use of a rail-to-rail op amp for the (1 or 3) op amps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a micro controller with millions of transistors to do what you need using a 555 and its few dozen transistors.

instead of connecting R2 to the junction of the diode and R1, just connect it to a voltage source of value between 0 % and 33 % of supply. This will cause the output low time to vary as you vary the source. If you bring it above 33 %, the circuit will stop oscillating completely (100 % low)

Comment: Could you include schematics?